# How to structure multiple small solutions with shared common code (moving to SVN)

Tags: svn, projects-and-solutions

I am about to migrate our code from VSS2005 to VisualSVN (and at the same time add in TeamCity).

This gives me the one-off chance of restructuring our code files/folders and I'm looking for some advice on how to strucure multiple, small solutions which often contain code either common to their "area" or to every project.

I have lots of small, internal applications - winforms, MVC3 sites, console/service apps etc., usually department specific.  Most departments have some "common" code for things they work with, and then there is general common code, such as extension methods, that are common to most projects.

By default VS2010 creates a "Solution" folder containing the .sln file, and then "Project" folders underneath.  That means everything is nicely discrete - but sharing projects is more difficult, since projects appear "solution specific"

I know you can reference anything, but on a disc structure it "looks" solution specific

```
CommonCode
--CCProj1
--CCProj2
HR.ServiceApp
-HR.ServiceApp.sln
--HR.SmallApp1.DAL
--HR.SmallApp1.Service
HR.WinFormsApp
-HR.WinFormsApp.sln
--HR.SmallApp2.DAL
--HR.SmallApp2.WinForms
```

An alternative could be to structure like this:

```
CommonCode
--CCProj1
--CCProj2
HR
-HR.Service.sln
-HR.WinForm.sln
--HR.DAL
--HR.Service
--HR.WinForms
```

which places all HR code under one single folder - but with multiple solutions could become a little unclear for new users?

Any advice on what other people commonly do would be VERY gratefully received (noting the move to SVN especially)

---

Another alternative

```
HR
-HR.Common
--HR.Common.Repository
---HR.Common.Repository.sln
----HR.Common.DAL
-----HR.Common.DAL.csproj
----HR.Common.BLL
-----HR.Common.BLL.csproj
-HR.Services
--HR.Services.Service1.sln
---HR.Services.Service1
----HR.Services.Service1.csproj
--HR.Services.Service2.sln
---HR.Services.Service2
----HR.Services.Service2.csproj
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must maintain separated the logical software configuration and the SVN structure. I would make the general structure like this:

```
- trunk
    - <general structure>
- branches
    - release_bugfix01
        - <general structure>
    - release02_rc1
        - <general structure>
- tags
    - release01
    - release02
```

Where "general structure" is:

```
 - common_code_1
 - common_code_2
 - project_one
 - project_three
 - winform01
 - humanresources_MVC3_site
 - console_service_app01
```

The internal structure of projects and common code can be in any shape you want and the logical dependecy among projects and common codes must be defined outside the repository.

You can read more about the standard layout in the [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.tour.importing.html#svn.tour.importing.layout)

Comment: Thanks - however, does this imply that "general structure" is all tied together? Or am I thinking about it incorrectly?  Very few of my projects are actually related to each other (in code terms), just the department they are for, although I do have shared "library" type code as well.

Comment: Also, from a quick "play" with SVN, it appears that projects also have Trunk/Branch/Tag folders?  So do I have T/B/Tg inside my T/B/Tg ?

Comment: You can choose the layout. You can define a global T/B/Tg to branch and tag the whole repository having only one trunk where all projects progress or have the projects (and common code) and inside each one the T/B/Tg layout. It's your project/projects life cycle what defines the repository layout, without knowing more of your product development cycle I can't say more.

Comment: Also maybe you must consider an approach based on several SVN repositories, one for each project.

Comment: Thanks Diego :)  Last one (I promise!) as I am still a little confused.  There is no clear project life-cycle...it's "as and when" for most of them - When you "Tag" a Trunk - does that take everything from the trunk...as it is at THAT moment, or can you specify part of the Trunk?  e.g.  If I am working on Proj1 and "diego" has just started Proj2 - then when I Tag the trunk, do I get your part completed code?

Comment: I lied!  I am coming from VSS2005 - there you "check out" to a base folder...and everything else is relative to that folder.  Does SVN do the same?  I think that is the source of my confusion - matching where something "sits" in SVN to where it "sits" locally on my HDD!

Comment: You create a tag from any directory. That includes any directory of the trunk. A tag is only a copy. So you can tag trunk/Proj1 to tags/Proj1_release01, for example.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to structuring is more of question for your team rather than a Q&A site. There are a variety of solutions as you have shown and each will have its merits. It all depends on what is most comfortable for your team.

In terms of how this ties in with SVN - it doesn't. SVN will allow you to structure however you like as it is agnostic of IDE/Programming language etc.

However, what you could do whilst you are in a transitional stage is to create several branches of your code made up into the varying structures so that you can demo each different way to your team. Once you have made a decision, merge the best code into trunk. In order to manage this branches, the top level of your SVN repository should have the folders trunk, branches and tags.